# Xamarin - Entity Framework - SqLite - GetItemsAsync : unable to open database file

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

In Visual studio 2017, I created a Cross-Platform Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)

- NETStandard 2.0
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core 2.2.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.2.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.0

I did a code first migration to Sqlite with Entity Framework following [the advice of Mark Smith](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101805/xamarin-android-entity-framework-core-2-and-migrations).  All tables are created successfully.  The database was seeded.

When I try to get the ItemsViewModel (see code below), I get the following exception (after 20 seconds) on the line --> List item list1 = await db.Person.ToListAsync();

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14:
>   'unable to open database file'.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc,
>   sqlite3 db)    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Strangely enough my test method TestSqLiteDataStoreAsync (see code below) correctly returns the expected list of items without causing an error.

Also the fact that it takes 20 seconds to get the error message indicates that it was able to find the database.  When you have a wrong db Name/path the error pops immediately.

Below you find the relevant code.  If you need anything more, let me know.
Any help on how to continue debugging is also welcome.   Or has anyone a basic working UWP code example I can compare mine with ? I have added a
[solution on Github](https://github.com/ywwyeu/Xamarin-Entity-Framework-SqLite) called 'temp'  with the needed database.  If one might have the time to try to reproduce the error :)
 Thx.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemsViewModel viewModel;

    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //1 code starts here
        BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    }

    async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));

        ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewItemPage()));
    }


    //adding 'async' did not solve the problem
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

          if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
            //2 code continues here 
            viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}


public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Browse";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        //3 code continues here 
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
        {
            var newItem = item as Item;
            Items.Add(newItem);
            await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
        });

    }

    //My test method
    public async Task<List<Item>> TestSqLiteDataStoreAsync()
    {
        SqLiteDataStore SqLiteDataStore = new SqLiteDataStore();
         return await SqLiteDataStore.GetItemsAsync(false);
    }



    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Items.Clear();
            //4 code continues here 
            var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}



public class SqLiteDataStore : IDataStore<Item>
{
    public string dbFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    public string fileName = "TestSqLite.db";

    public SqLiteDataStore()  { }

    public async Task<List<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Models.MyContext(Path.Combine(dbFolder, fileName)))
            {
                List<Person> list1 = new List<Person>();
                List<Item> list2 = new List<Item>();

                //5 I get the error here
                list1 = await db.Person.ToListAsync();

                foreach (Person person in list1)
                {
                    Item item = new Item(person);
                    list2.Add(item);
                }
                return list2;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
     }


    public async Task<bool> AddItemAsync(Item item)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> UpdateItemAsync(Item item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<Item> GetItemAsync(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` with `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` and see if it helps.

Comment: I found that creating an empty file, with the same filename as the database file, would then allow me to create the database, without getting this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we had mentioned before, simply replacing `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` with `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` will solve the problem. You can check [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2) for details about each option. And now your items are loading properly:

[image]

---

**Answering your follow-up comments:**

Yes, the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you posted on github now runs without any problems **after** changing to `LoadApplicationData` like we described, including your test code, as shown below:

```
[3/10/2019 4:26:28 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.02] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.0 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.27129.04)
[3/10/2019 4:26:31 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:03.41]   Discovering: XUnitTestProject1
[3/10/2019 4:26:31 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:03.61]   Discovered:  XUnitTestProject1
[3/10/2019 4:26:31 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:11.5651246) ==========
[3/10/2019 4:26:31 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[3/10/2019 4:26:32 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.0 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.27129.04)
[3/10/2019 4:26:33 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.63]   Discovering: XUnitTestProject1
[3/10/2019 4:26:33 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.70]   Discovered:  XUnitTestProject1
[3/10/2019 4:26:33 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.70]   Starting:    XUnitTestProject1
[3/10/2019 4:26:35 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:02.60]   Finished:    XUnitTestProject1
[3/10/2019 4:26:35 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:03.9952011) ==========
```

[image]

If we switch back to `Personal` folder, we get the same exception you reported:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The reason why you can run your test code but not the app is probably because these two have different permission requirements.

Please remember that for this to work in both cases, you have not only to change `Environment.SpecialFolder`, but also, place `TestSqLite.db` in the corresponding folder. In our case the folder is something like this:

```
C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Packages\0eea1ae6-65c3-42e9-9a50-869730e52f63_2ft3g98yvwh70\LocalState
```

Obviously you should get a similar but slightly different path.

---

**Comments on result verification:** It takes only a couple minutes to perform this simple verification procedure. Here's what happens when we switch back to `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`, having `TestSqLite.db` in its corresponding `C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents` folder.

As depicted below, the app takes a longer than normal time (cut short here to limit upload size) to load the initial **Browse** page. When it finally does, the initial page is empty. Switching between the **About** page and then back to **Browse** page causes the app to hang (wait for it). Again, this is a simple procedure that takes little time and no effort to perform.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem.  Changing the path to retrieve the database did not solve my problem.  In my code it points to the correct database (my testcode works).    I see you managed to run my code using my sample sql lite database (correct ?).     This will help me to find my error.

Comment: @ywwy please see our updated answer. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @ywwy please mark our answer as accepted, it's the right thing to do... our suggestion eliminated the exception you reported, the app loads its items and runs clean now, and so do the test code, as documented by *overwhelming evidence* in our post.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and your answer is probably correct, just give me some time to confirm it.

Comment: @ywwy please see **Comments on result verification** section on our updated answer.

Comment: using  Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData AND copying the database in that folder solved the problem.   Apparently you cannot choose the path to the database freely.  thx again for your extensive testing.

Comment: @ywwy sure, we had mentioned that in our first update. As for DB file location, if you ask me, a small price to pay in the name of security. I would not want ANY app snooping into my `Documents` folder anyway...:O) There might be a way to use a custom string in the file path rather than the cryptic standard `Guid` one. But that could be the subject for another interesting question...:O)

Comment: @ywwy one more thing: even if there is a way to use a custom folder for the DB file, it would still not invalidate our answer, given that, in the name of fairness, you shouldn't change your original question in the middle of getting an answer for it...:O)

Answer (score 0):

According to get the

> "Unable to open database file"

error maybe you're pointing the code at a file that doesn't exist.

A "Table not found" error means it found the database, but not the table you were looking for. On the other hand, "Unable to open database file" means that it couldn't even find the database, and didn't even bother looking for a table. You're much closer to it working correctly when you're getting "Table not found".

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question. When I run my test method  "TestSqLiteDataStoreAsync" with Xunit, I get no error.   The path is correct, the database exists and I even get a list of items back.     When the "GetItemsAsync" gets called from the "ItemsViewModel" class, I get the exception.

Comment: Locking issue? Can not open also can mean * Rights or * something else holds a lock an thus the file can not be opened.

Comment: @TomTom indeed could have been the reason. I checked the file properties and set full rights to everyone :).  To no avail.   The test method run from XUnit doesn't have the problem.